use of aurai and vais
My web search result says it is okay to say both

J'aurai vingt ans l'année prochaine.
Je vais avoir vingt ans l'année prochaine.

when I want to say I'm turning 20 next year. But it says the former is more formal and direct whereas the latter is more informal and conversational.
I would like to ask if that explanation is correct.
Also, my French grammar book says the use of 'aurai' in the first sentence implies that it is a distant and vague future event. I would be very delighted if someone could confirm whether I can still say, in December, when your birthday is in January,

J'aurai vingt ans l'année prochaine.


J'aurai is futur simple je vais avoir is futur proche. Is the answer to this question Différence entre le futur proche et le futur simple any help to you?

Demain, j'aurai vingt ans.

@JJH Your search results/books are correct in both cases.

@guillaume31 Hmm, no. The simple future doesn't imply the event is distant nor that it is a vague one. One minute before their birthday, someone can say : J'aurai un an de plus dans une minute. Not a vague event neither a distant future.

@jiliagre in this context, yes. In decreasing order of closeness and immediate relevance to what the speaker is saying: "j'ai vingt ans l'année prochaine" < "je vais avoir vingt ans..." < "j'aurai vingt ans..."


[futur simple] is more formal and direct whereas [futur proche] is
more informal and conversational.

That much is correct, and the only rule to remember about expressing future tense in French, really.
As its name states, futur proche implies that the event is near, but it is not uncommon to hear:

Je vais aller en Thaïlande en octobre 2025!

And the other way around. For instance it is currently half past 11 in the morning, and this sentence could also be said:

J'irai manger là-bas ce midi. Tu viens avec moi?

However, both examples would typically be found daily oral speech, or written works including contemporary-manner dialogues.
Therefore, your last example could very well be both said (because orality doesn't care much about the "proche" rule) and written (because futur simple could also formally be used for nearer cases, - December to January is still around a month and works too).
I would shorten the tip as: futur proche informal usage only stems from using it for further events. Anything else about future tenses (including using futur simple for close events) is formally correct.
I also agree that the "vague" criterion is rather irrelevant for both tenses (both can perfectly be used to refer to an uncertain/unclear event).
Happy learning.

further events meaning more or events further away in time?

@Lambie Further events in time!

Well, I think we'd just say future events, then.
